# Which meta tag takes priority

Tags: html, meta-tags

If there is a meta tag in the  header section
`<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX,FOLLOW">` which I do not have access to  ( cms company that gives me limited functionality) but the site does allow me to add meta tags and I add in `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NONE">` which gets added in the header section after the first one mentioned, which meta tag takes priority?

I don't want my site indexed but I can't remove `<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX,FOLLOW">`

Clearer example:

```
<HTML>
  <HEAD>
    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX,FOLLOW">
    <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NONE"> 
    <!-- what will search engine spiders do? -->
  </HEAD>
```

Comment: Which meta tags are there, and which ones are you adding?

Comment: I don't get your question. What do you mean by priority? Each meta tag has it's own functionality..

Comment: Whilst better suited for [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/); this is actually quite a good question

Comment: `robots.txt` is the only safe solution how to regulate bots' access.

Comment: It seems that the robots.txt takes precedence. So use that one. But leave the extra meta just to be extra sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try testing it here: http://www.seocentro.com/tools/search-engines/metatag-analyzer.html

I would imagine that different spiders probably handle that situation differently though, so I wouldn't rely on the results. Just as spiders can completely ignore your meta tags, they are free to interpret them a number of ways depending on how they are written.

Answer (score 1):

from http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.nl/2007/03/using-robots-meta-tag.html

> If content values conflict, we will use the most restrictive. So, if
>   the page has these meta tags:
>
> ```
> <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="NOINDEX">
> <META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX">
> ```
>
> We will obey the NOINDEX value.